# Trying to extract portion of csv to numpy array

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I've been at this problem for a few days and tried a couple of different approaches, but I can't seem to get it quite right.  This is the a simplified version of my csv data file: testme.csv

```
   "Name", "City", "State", "1996-04", "1996-05", "1996-06", "1996-07"
   "Bob", "Portland", "OR", 100000, 120000, 140000, 160000
   "Sally", "Eugene", "OR", 50000, 75000, 80000, 90000
   "Peter", "San Francisco", "CA", , , 440000, 500000
```

I want to extract the numbers as 2D array which I wish to do some math upon.  However I've got these text fields before that I need to ignore.  Also, some rows won't have numbers for all of the columns, but once the numbers start they are continuous to the right (i.e. some rows have empty items for the first several columns), and this can be different per row.  Additionally, the real data set has hundreds of rows and dozens of columns

This is some of what I've tried:

```
    import csv
    import numpy as np

    filename = "testme.csv"

    ifile = open(filename, 'r')
    header1 = ifile.readline()

    reader = csv.reader(ifile)
    A = np.array([]).reshape(0, 4)

    for row in reader:
        print row
        print row[3:]
        A = np.vstack([A, row[3:]])

    print A
```

And then I get this:

```
  ['Bob', ' "Portland"', ' "OR"', ' 100000', ' 120000', ' 140000', ' 160000']
    [' 100000', ' 120000', ' 140000', ' 160000']
    ['Sally', ' "Eugene"', ' "OR"', ' 50000', ' 75000', ' 80000', ' 90000']
    [' 50000', ' 75000', ' 80000', ' 90000']
    ['Peter', ' "San Francisco"', ' "CA"', ' ', ' ', ' 440000', ' 500000']
    [' ', ' ', ' 440000', ' 500000']
    [[' 100000' ' 120000' ' 140000' ' 160000']
     [' 50000' ' 75000' ' 80000' ' 90000']
     [' ' ' ' ' 440000' ' 500000']]
```

I'm close, but the elements are all now literal strings.  Is there an easier way to do this and get numbers instead or do I know go through this and convert each element to numbers?  And the empty elements I could benefit from clamping them to zero.

Thank you for advice and help ahead of time!

## Aaron

Update (8/1/16)
I did go with the genfromtxt method as that matched what I needed a lot.  Here is the result for posterity and others

```
    import csv
    import numpy as np

    NumIgnoreFirstCols = 3
    filename = "testme2.csv"

    ifile = open(filename, 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(ifile)
    header1 = next(reader)
    numcols = len(header1)
    #Find number of cols for usecol in genfromtxt
    print("numcols", numcols)
    ifile.close()

    print(range(NumIgnoreFirstCols, numcols))

    aMatrix = np.genfromtxt(filename, skip_header=1, delimiter=',', usecols=range(NumIgnoreFirstCols,numcols), dtype=int)

    print aMatrix

    normalizedMatrix = np.where(aMatrix<0, 0, aMatrix)
    print(normalizedMatrix)

    minValue = np.amin(normalizedMatrix)
    maxValue = np.amax(normalizedMatrix)
    print (minValue, maxValue)
```

Thanks again for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your sample, `numpy` `genfromtxt` works:

```
In [166]: np.genfromtxt('stack38627130.csv',names=True,delimiter=',',dtype=None)

Out[166]: 
array([(b'"Bob"', b' "Portland"', b' "OR"', 100000, 120000, 140000, 160000),
       (b'"Sally"', b' "Eugene"', b' "OR"', 50000, 75000, 80000, 90000),
       (b'"Peter"', b' "San Francisco"', b' "CA"', -1, -1, 440000, 500000)], 
      dtype=[('Name', 'S7'), ('City', 'S16'), ('State', 'S5'), ('199604', '<i4'), ('199605', '<i4'), ('199606', '<i4'), ('199607', '<i4')])
```

This is a 1d structured array; you access columns by field name (here derived from your header line)

```
In [167]: data=_
In [168]: data['199604']
Out[168]: array([100000,  50000,     -1])
In [169]: data['199607']
Out[169]: array([160000,  90000, 500000])
```

The missing fields are filled with `-1`.  I think that can be changed.

There are other parameters for setting field names if you don't like the deduced ones.

Read can be restricted to the numeric columns; different fill depending on the `dtype`.

```
In [171]: np.genfromtxt('stack38627130.csv',skip_header=1,delimiter=',',usecols=
     ...: [3,4,5,6])
Out[171]: 
array([[ 100000.,  120000.,  140000.,  160000.],
       [  50000.,   75000.,   80000.,   90000.],
       [     nan,      nan,  440000.,  500000.]])
In [172]: np.genfromtxt('stack38627130.csv',skip_header=1,delimiter=',',usecols=
     ...: [3,4,5,6],dtype=int)
Out[172]: 
array([[100000, 120000, 140000, 160000],
       [ 50000,  75000,  80000,  90000],
       [    -1,     -1, 440000, 500000]])
```

Now we get a 2d array.

I believe `pandas` handles missing fields better, but as long as those fields are marked with the delimiter, `genfromtxt` shouldn't have problems.

`genfromtxt` roughly does:

```
result = []
for row in reader:
    data = row[3:]
    data = [float(x) for x in data]
    result.append(data)
result = np.array(result)
```

`np.array` can do the float conversion if all the strings convert properly; it does not handle the empty ones or `nan`.  Generally collecting a list of values is better than repeated `vstack` (or concatenates).

Comment: I did go with this solution as it matched most of what I needed. I'll post what I used finally as well

Answer (score 1):

If -- and that's a big if (I kid) -- you can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
from StringIO import StringIO
s = StringIO('''   "Name", "City", "State", "1996-04", "1996-05", "1996-06", "1996-07"
                   "Bob", "Portland", "OR", 100000, 120000, 140000, 160000
                   "Peter", "San Francisco", "CA", , , 440000, 500000   ''')
df = pd.read_csv(s,skipinitialspace=True)
```

Getting there...

```
>>> df
    Name           City State   1996-04   1996-05  1996-06  1996-07
0    Bob       Portland    OR  100000.0  120000.0   140000   160000
1  Peter  San Francisco    CA       NaN       NaN   440000   500000
```

Clamp to zero as you say:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```

I think this is the end result you wanted:

```
>>> df
    Name           City State   1996-04   1996-05  1996-06  1996-07
0    Bob       Portland    OR  100000.0  120000.0   140000   160000
1  Peter  San Francisco    CA       0.0       0.0   440000   500000
```

Comment: The right tool for the right job. Numpy is great, but it doesn't handle heterogeneous (different) data types.

Comment: `numpy` can handle heterogeneous data types - with structured arrays.  People use `genfromtxt` for that all the time.  Lots of questions about that.